SymPy and dictionary variables
I need to use for SymPy operations a number of variables that depend on other parameters in the code. As  I understand, a dictionary is used normally when the number of variables is not known in advance. However, SymPy does not allow to declare dictionary variables (say, d[1][1]) symbols and use them in symbolic operations like deriving expressions with respect to them.
What would be a proper solution for this situation?

Welcome to [so]. This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. It is not possible to provide a specific answer without you providing sufficient information to understand your problem. Please see: Why is Can someone help me? not an actual question?  for more details.

This is not about tutoring. This is an extension of the question link It is a common practice to use a dictionary when the number of variables is not known in advance but SymPy doesn't seem to be able to work with dictionary components as symbols.

It's not very clear what you want to do, but is it something like this?
>>> from sympy import *
>>> from collections import defaultdict


You could also use a function (which behaves better wrt differentiation) but it would be accessed as d[1](0) instead of d[1][0]:
>>> s=numbered_symbols('x',cls=Function)
>>> d=defaultdict(lambda:next(s))
>>> (d[0](1) + 2*d[1](1)).diff(d[1](1))
2


Thank you! How could I calculate a derivative with respect to, say, d[2][1]? If I define a function and then use f.diff(d[2][1]) it results in Value Error

appended to answer
